# Scheduler not running in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, scheduler

I have created a Spring Boot application. I have configured my class that contains the scheduler method `startService()`. 
Below is my code :

**Service Class :**

```
package com.mk.service;  
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.mk.envers.model.BossExtChange;
import com.mk.envers.model.BossExtChangeRepository;

@Component
public class EnverseDemoService {

    @Autowired
    BossExtChangeRepository bossExtChangeRepository;

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 30000)
    public void startService() {
        System.out.println("Calling startService()");
        BossExtChange bossExtChange = bossExtChangeRepository.findById(5256868L);
        System.out.println("bossExtChange.getDescription()--->"+bossExtChange.getDescription());
        System.out.println("Ending startService()");
    }
}
```

**Main Class :**

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class EnverseDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EnverseDemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I have annotated the class as `@Component` and also method as `@Scheduled(fixedRate = 30000)` that will running as a scheduler. But while running the application as Spring Boot the scheduler does not trigger. The console show the below message:

```
2016-02-03 10:56:47.708  INFO 10136 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup 
2016-02-03 10:56:47.721  INFO 10136 --- [           main] com.mk.envers.EnverseDemoApplication     : Started EnverseDemoApplication in 3.231 seconds (JVM running for 3.623)
2016-02-03 10:56:47.721  INFO 10136 --- [       Thread-2] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@49e202ad: startup date [Wed Feb 03 10:56:44 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-02-03 10:56:47.721  INFO 10136 --- [       Thread-2] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown 
2016-02-03 10:56:47.736  INFO 10136 --- [       Thread-2] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
```

Can anyone please help me out.

Comment: Remove `@PropertySource` as that is already loaded by default. Is the `EnverseDemoApplication` in the same or in a super package of `EnverseDemoService`? (You omitted the `package` clause so it is hard to tell. ). If it sn't your bean isn't picked up and no scheduling/threads will be alive.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was finally able to solve the above issue, I changed the package of my service class **EnverseDemoService** from `package com.mk.service;` to  `com.mk.envers.service;`. This is because if the main configuration class **EnverseDemoApplication** is present in the package `com.mk.envers`. All the other classes in the boot application should be in the qualifying package. `Eg: com.mk.envers.*;`

Comment: I had similar issue where the scheduler wont start. The package of the scheduler jobs should be under the main Application class's package.

Answer (score 43):

I was able to solve the issue, I forgot to provide @service level annotation,
I have created the check List for @Scheduler, kindly go through every point one by one, It will help you to solve the issue.

1. Check for the @EnableScheduling on SpringBoot Main class.
2. Scheduled method should be annotated with @Scheduled, Follow the @Scheduled Method rules. **a method should have the void return type, a method should not accept any parameters.**
3. Make sure the class should be annotated with @Service or @Component Annotation so SpringBoot can make the object of that class.
4. The package of the scheduler jobs should be under the main Application class's package. e.g com.company is your main application class package then scheduler class package should be com.company.scheduler,
5. If you are using Cron expression confirm the same e.g @Scheduled( cron = "0 0/2 * * * ?"), This Cron expression will schedule the task for every 2 min.

**Feel free to add more points in the comment so it will help to solve the issue.**

Comment: Thanks! Checking for the `@EnableScheduling` was what helped me: I didn't add it to my application main class...

Comment: Thanks adding @Service annotation helped me

Comment: Thanks! Just want to add that for the @EnableScheduling annotation also can be added to the configuration class:

Answer (score 38):

May be you can solve this problem by adding the **@ComponentScan** annotation in the configuration file

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.mk.service")
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class EnverseDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EnverseDemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 19):

It must be that you forgot to add @EnableScheduling annotation in your app class.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        context = SpringApplication.run(YouApplication.class, args);
    }
```

Comment: Though `@EnableScheduling` is there in the question asked, but this answer still helps in highlighting this.

Answer (score 7):

In my case, was the `lazy-initialization` with value `true` which was preventing my `@Component` to be loaded by Spring at startup and `@Scheduled` method was never running.

Make sure the Spring Boot [lazy initialization](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-lazy-initialization) is disabled.

Answer (score 2):

Please check if in application.properties you have
"spring.main.lazy-initialization=true"

Remove this from application.properties.

Even if you have all the configuration correct, this simple line will enable lazy loading due to which your @Component will initalize during application start.

Answer (score 0):

As Swapnil already mentioned all the check-points to make sure while using cron. One additional thing you should do:
Always verify your cron expression whether it's in right format or not, using below reference site - http://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html#

Answer (score 0):

In my case I only add `@Component` at the same class I used the `@Scheduled`

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had an abstract @Service class containing the @Scheduled method, removing the abstract keyword it worked.