# Spring TaskScheduler not starting all @Scheduled Jobs

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, tomcat, scheduled-tasks

Our Spring project doesn't start all the @Scheduled job functions, please help us figure our why.

Here is our configuration:

```
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAsync
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AppConfig.class);

    @Bean
    public TaskScheduler taskScheduler() {
        LOGGER.info("Configuring TaskScheduler");
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.setPoolSize(500);
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("ThreadPoolTaskScheduler");
        return threadPoolTaskScheduler;
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
        LOGGER.info("Configuring TaskExecutor. Available Processors=" + Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(500);
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
}
```

As you can see, we are configuring both the TaskScheduler and the TaskExecutor.

Of course, our XMLs are configured too

```
<task:annotation-driven executor="executor" scheduler="scheduler" proxy-target-class="true" />
<task:executor id="executor" pool-size="200" />
<task:scheduler id="scheduler" pool-size="200" />
```

It seems that for some reason, only SOME of our @Scheduled Tasks are starting as required - but the rest of them do not.

We don't see any errors or warnings in the logs:

The @Configuration is running as planned, and prints the messages to the logs.

> ```
> Configuring TaskScheduler
> Configuring TaskExecutor. Available Processors=16
> ```

All of our @Scheduled tasks reside in @Component(s);

Comment: Do you use both the annotation-based and XML-based configurations at the same time? If so - why? Also, if the problem is related to the scheduled jobs, your task executer is irrelevant here.

Comment: @dekkard I followed your advice and updated the XML to <task:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" mode="aspectj" />

Comment: Well that was not my advice. I just mentioned that your task executor config doesn't have anything to do with scheduled jobs and is not related to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was eventually solved by reference of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35169161/scheduler-not-running-in-spring-boot)

The missing part was the **NAMESPACE**

the AppConfig resided in **package** com.companyname.service

while some other @Scheduled task resided in other packages.

We moved the AppConfig to com.companyname

All the @Scheduled tasks started to work.

Quoting [Swapnil Pasarkar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67284579/1743693):

> "The package of the scheduler jobs should be under the main
> Application class's package. e.g com.company is your main application
> class package then scheduler class package should be
> com.company.scheduler"

Comment: One more thing, is that I updated the pool size to 900