# How to schedule a job in spring boot without declaring the class as @Component

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I am trying to schedule the a method in my `CustomerFeed` this class has a method `consumeActivity` I followed this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67284579/14237523) checklist. I am fulfilling all requirement except declaring  `CustomerFeed` , because I have some specific requirement please refer the below code to understand the bean creation of `CustomerFeed`

```
@Configuration
public class IacFeederFactory
        implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor, EnvironmentAware { 

@Override
public void postProcessBeanFactory(final ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
    Map<String, ActivityRepository> repos = createSourceDbRepositories();
    Map<String, CustomerFeedDefinition> feeds = Binder.get(environment)
            .bind(CONFIG_NAMESPACE, FeedConfig.class)
            .orElse(FeedConfig.empty())
            .getFeed();
    for (Map.Entry<String, CustomerFeedDefinition> e : feeds.entrySet()) {
        final String customerId = e.getKey();
        final CustomerFeedDefinition conf = e.getValue();
        ActivityRepository repository = repos.get(conf.getSourceDb());
        beanFactory.registerSingleton("feed-" + customerId, new CustomerFeed(customerId, repository));
    }
}
```

}

Now I want to know is there any way to doing it except using @Component, as it is also a spring managed bean.